# Left join fetching duplication

Tags: hibernate, jpa, fetch, lazy-evaluation

I have some troubles with JPA(Hibernate) and LazyFetching

I have some **entities**:
Quest, Reward, Contract

**Relationship**(all are Lazy):

- Quest One2Many Reward; Quest Many2Many Contract;
- Contract One2Many Reward; Contract Many2Many Quest;
- Reward Many2One Query; Reward Many2One Contract;

DB contains this data:
Quest1 has Reward1, Reward2 and Contract1, Contract2;

In come cases I need Quest with its Rewards & Contracts, so i do in JPArepository:

```
@Query("select Q from Quest Q left join fetch Q.rewards left join fetch Q.contracts")
List<Quest> getAllQuestsWithRewardsAndContracts();
```

the problem is that I recive
One quest with 4(but it has only 2) rewards(Reward1,Reward2,Reward1,Reward2) and two Contracts.
I get rewards duplicated!
I dont understand why !
If i do so:

```
@Query("select distinct Q from Quest Q left join fetch Q.rewards")
List<Quest> getAllQuestsWithRewardsRew();
```

I recive one quest with two rewards(Reward1, Reward2)

Why ? Why i have duplication ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the nature how Hibernate works. It does not remove duplicate generated out of LEFT OUTER JOINS. You can get explicitly specify that you need distinct results

For example if you were using criteria to fetch data you could specify

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Check out the SQL being generated when you fetch the data. Here is a FAQ which explains more about why Hibernate behaves this way [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-AdvancedProblems#Hibernate_does_not_return_distinct_results_for_a_query_with_outer_join_fetching_enabled_for_a_collection_even_if_I_use_the_distinct_keyword)

Also in the first query you are loading multiple collections (Rewards and Contracts) in the same SQL which might result in  a Cartesian product. Hibernate has a **Futures** API which helps in loading multiple children collections using simpler SQLs than those which generate cartesian products. (I am not sure if Futures would work with JPA)

Answer (score 0):

One table may have more rows then another. So give some condition to avoid duplication...